# Shopify create customer blocked by captcha challenge

Tags: javascript, http, axios, shopify, recaptcha

I'm creating a tool that will create accounts for a certain shopify store using the following http request:

```
await axios.post(
            siteURL + "/account",
            qs.stringify({
                "form_type": "create_customer",
                "customer[first_name]": firstName,
                "customer[last_name]": lastName,
                "customer[email]": email,
                "customer[password]": password,
            }),
            {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36"
                }
            }
        );
```

Now, this request works perfectly for sites like https://kith.com or https://packershoes.com but for sites like https://neighborhood.jp or https://windandsea.jp/ this request throws the following 404 error:

```
ClientRequest {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    socket: [Function],
    abort: [Function],
    aborted: [Function],
    error: [Function],
    timeout: [Function],
    prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
  },
  _eventsCount: 6,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  outputData: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
  _last: true,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: false,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
  sendDate: false,
  _removedConnection: false,
  _removedContLen: false,
  _removedTE: false,
  _contentLength: 0,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: true,
  _headerSent: true,
  socket: TLSSocket {
    _tlsOptions: {
      allowHalfOpen: undefined,
      pipe: false,
      secureContext: [SecureContext],
      isServer: false,
      requestCert: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: true,
      session: <Buffer 30 82 06 da 02 01 01 02 02 03 04 04 02 13 02 04 20 fa 3e 8f ba c6 59 fb 94 86 e3 68 63 3f 43 fd 86 10 11 07 97 d7 10 1e d2 
99 55 b6 36 f3 e2 3d a1 04 ... 1708 more bytes>,
      ALPNProtocols: undefined,
      requestOCSP: undefined,
      enableTrace: undefined,
      pskCallback: undefined
    },
    _secureEstablished: true,
    _securePending: false,
    _newSessionPending: false,
    _controlReleased: true,
    _SNICallback: null,
    servername: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
    alpnProtocol: false,
    authorized: true,
    authorizationError: null,
    encrypted: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      close: [Array],
      end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd],
      newListener: [Function: keylogNewListener],
      secure: [Function: onConnectSecure],
      session: [Function],
      free: [Function: onFree],
      agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
      error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
      finish: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 9,
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: null,
      pipesCount: 0,
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrain: 0,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    readable: true,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: true,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: true,
      ended: true,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      bufferedRequest: null,
      lastBufferedRequest: null,
      pendingcb: 1,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      bufferedRequestCount: 0,
      corkedRequestsFree: [Object]
    },
    writable: false,
    allowHalfOpen: false,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: undefined,
    _server: null,
    ssl: TLSWrap {
      _parent: [TCP],
      _parentWrap: undefined,
      _secureContext: [SecureContext],
      reading: true,
      onhandshakestart: [Function: noop],
      onhandshakedone: [Function],
      onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
      onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
      onkeylog: [Function: onkeylogclient],
      onerror: [Function: onerror],
      [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular]
    },
    _requestCert: true,
    _rejectUnauthorized: true,
    parser: null,
    _httpMessage: [Circular],
    [Symbol(res)]: TLSWrap {
      _parent: [TCP],
      _parentWrap: undefined,
      _secureContext: [SecureContext],
      reading: true,
      onhandshakestart: [Function: noop],
      onhandshakedone: [Function],
      onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
      onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
      onkeylog: [Function: onkeylogclient],
      onerror: [Function: onerror],
      [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular]
    },
    [Symbol(asyncId)]: 205,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TLSWrap {
      _parent: [TCP],
      _parentWrap: undefined,
      _secureContext: [SecureContext],
      reading: true,
      onhandshakestart: [Function: noop],
      onhandshakedone: [Function],
      onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
      onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
      onkeylog: [Function: onkeylogclient],
      onerror: [Function: onerror],
      [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular]
    },
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(connect-options)]: {
      rejectUnauthorized: true,
      ciphers: 'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!CAMELLIA',    
      checkServerIdentity: [Function: checkServerIdentity],
      minDHSize: 1024,
      session: <Buffer 30 82 06 da 02 01 01 02 02 03 04 04 02 13 02 04 20 fa 3e 8f ba c6 59 fb 94 86 e3 68 63 3f 43 fd 86 10 11 07 97 d7 10 1e d2 
99 55 b6 36 f3 e2 3d a1 04 ... 1708 more bytes>,
      protocol: 'https:',
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      path: null,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: null,
      hostname: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
      port: 443,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/challenge',
      slashes: true,
      host: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
      hash: null,
      search: null,
      query: null,
      href: 'https://www.neighborhood.jp/challenge',
      _defaultAgent: [Agent],
      servername: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
      _agentKey: 'www.neighborhood.jp:443::::::::::::::::::',
      encoding: null,
      singleUse: true
    }
  },
  connection: TLSSocket {
    _tlsOptions: {
      allowHalfOpen: undefined,
      pipe: false,
      secureContext: [SecureContext],
      isServer: false,
      requestCert: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: true,
      session: <Buffer 30 82 06 da 02 01 01 02 02 03 04 04 02 13 02 04 20 fa 3e 8f ba c6 59 fb 94 86 e3 68 63 3f 43 fd 86 10 11 07 97 d7 10 1e d2 
99 55 b6 36 f3 e2 3d a1 04 ... 1708 more bytes>,
      ALPNProtocols: undefined,
      requestOCSP: undefined,
      enableTrace: undefined,
      pskCallback: undefined
    },
    _secureEstablished: true,
    _securePending: false,
    _newSessionPending: false,
    _controlReleased: true,
    _SNICallback: null,
    servername: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
    alpnProtocol: false,
    authorized: true,
    authorizationError: null,
    encrypted: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      close: [Array],
      end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd],
      newListener: [Function: keylogNewListener],
      secure: [Function: onConnectSecure],
      session: [Function],
      free: [Function: onFree],
      agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
      error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
      finish: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 9,
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: null,
      pipesCount: 0,
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrain: 0,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    readable: true,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: true,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: true,
      ended: true,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      bufferedRequest: null,
      lastBufferedRequest: null,
      pendingcb: 1,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      bufferedRequestCount: 0,
      corkedRequestsFree: [Object]
    },
    writable: false,
    allowHalfOpen: false,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: undefined,
    _server: null,
    ssl: TLSWrap {
      _parent: [TCP],
      _parentWrap: undefined,
      _secureContext: [SecureContext],
      reading: true,
      onhandshakestart: [Function: noop],
      onhandshakedone: [Function],
      onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
      onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
      onkeylog: [Function: onkeylogclient],
      onerror: [Function: onerror],
      [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular]
    },
    _requestCert: true,
    _rejectUnauthorized: true,
    parser: null,
    _httpMessage: [Circular],
    [Symbol(res)]: TLSWrap {
      _parent: [TCP],
      _parentWrap: undefined,
      _secureContext: [SecureContext],
      reading: true,
      onhandshakestart: [Function: noop],
      onhandshakedone: [Function],
      onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
      onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
      onkeylog: [Function: onkeylogclient],
      onerror: [Function: onerror],
      [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular]
    },
    [Symbol(asyncId)]: 205,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TLSWrap {
      _parent: [TCP],
      _parentWrap: undefined,
      _secureContext: [SecureContext],
      reading: true,
      onhandshakestart: [Function: noop],
      onhandshakedone: [Function],
      onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
      onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
      onkeylog: [Function: onkeylogclient],
      onerror: [Function: onerror],
      [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular]
    },
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(connect-options)]: {
      rejectUnauthorized: true,
      ciphers: 'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!CAMELLIA',    
      checkServerIdentity: [Function: checkServerIdentity],
      minDHSize: 1024,
      session: <Buffer 30 82 06 da 02 01 01 02 02 03 04 04 02 13 02 04 20 fa 3e 8f ba c6 59 fb 94 86 e3 68 63 3f 43 fd 86 10 11 07 97 d7 10 1e d2 
99 55 b6 36 f3 e2 3d a1 04 ... 1708 more bytes>,
      protocol: 'https:',
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      path: null,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: null,
      hostname: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
      port: 443,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/challenge',
      slashes: true,
      host: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
      hash: null,
      search: null,
      query: null,
      href: 'https://www.neighborhood.jp/challenge',
      _defaultAgent: [Agent],
      servername: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
      _agentKey: 'www.neighborhood.jp:443::::::::::::::::::',
      encoding: null,
      singleUse: true
    }
  },
  _header: 'GET /challenge HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
    'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36\r\n' +
    'Host: www.neighborhood.jp\r\n' +
    'Connection: close\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
  agent: Agent {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      free: [Function],
      newListener: [Function: maybeEnableKeylog]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    defaultPort: 443,
    protocol: 'https:',
    options: { path: null },
    requests: {},
    sockets: { 'www.neighborhood.jp:443::::::::::::::::::': [Array] },
    freeSockets: {},
    keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
    keepAlive: false,
    maxSockets: Infinity,
    maxFreeSockets: 256,
    maxCachedSessions: 100,
    _sessionCache: { map: [Object], list: [Array] },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  socketPath: undefined,
  method: 'GET',
  insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
  path: '/challenge',
  _ended: true,
  res: IncomingMessage {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: null,
      pipesCount: 0,
      flowing: true,
      ended: true,
      endEmitted: true,
      reading: false,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrain: 0,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    readable: false,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      data: [Function: handleStreamData],
      error: [Function: handleStreamError]
    },
    _eventsCount: 3,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 205,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    connection: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 205,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    httpVersionMajor: 1,
    httpVersionMinor: 1,
    httpVersion: '1.1',
    complete: true,
    headers: {
      date: 'Thu, 04 Jun 2020 05:44:00 GMT',
      'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      connection: 'close',
      'set-cookie': [Array],
      'x-sorting-hat-podid': '76',
      'x-sorting-hat-shopid': '22297968717',
      'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
      'x-shopid': '22297968717',
      'x-shardid': '76',
      'content-language': 'ja',
      'x-shopify-generated-cart-token': 'ec01373dbd31b4829ecfb3d179924f78',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=7889238',
      'x-alternate-cache-key': 'cacheable:57d4938b6eec0948258100bed68b0d2d',
      'x-cache': 'miss',
      'x-shopify-stage': 'production',
      'content-security-policy': "block-all-mixed-content; frame-ancestors 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests; report-uri /csp-report?source%5Baction%5D=challenge&source%5Bapp%5D=Shopify&source%5Bcontroller%5D=storefront_section%2Fcaptcha_throttle&source%5Bsection%5D=storefront&source%5Buuid%5D=253b7e9b-919d-49b2-b508-865869943bbe",
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-download-options': 'noopen',
      'x-permitted-cross-domain-policies': 'none',
      'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block; report=/xss-report?source%5Baction%5D=challenge&source%5Bapp%5D=Shopify&source%5Bcontroller%5D=storefront_section%2Fcaptcha_throttle&source%5Bsection%5D=storefront&source%5Buuid%5D=253b7e9b-919d-49b2-b508-865869943bbe',
      'x-dc': 'gcp-us-central1,gcp-us-east1,gcp-us-east1',
      'x-request-id': '253b7e9b-919d-49b2-b508-865869943bbe',
      'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
      'cf-request-id': '031f74a5e20000bcc658ae1200000001',
      'expect-ct': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
      server: 'cloudflare',
      'cf-ray': '59df56e96822bcc6-SEA',
      'alt-svc': 'h3-27=":443"; ma=86400'
    },
    rawHeaders: [
      'Date',
      'Thu, 04 Jun 2020 05:44:00 GMT',
      'Content-Type',
      'text/html; charset=utf-8',
      'Transfer-Encoding',
      'chunked',
      'Connection',
      'close',
      'Set-Cookie',
      '__cfduid=db595ddcb05d8c2398f57eb5b22bc62fb1591249440; expires=Sat, 04-Jul-20 05:44:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.www.neighborhood.jp; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax',
      'X-Sorting-Hat-PodId',
      '76',
      'X-Sorting-Hat-ShopId',
      '22297968717',
      'X-Frame-Options',
      'DENY',
      'X-ShopId',
      '22297968717',
      'X-ShardId',
      '76',
      'Content-Language',
      'ja',
      'X-Shopify-Generated-Cart-Token',
      'ec01373dbd31b4829ecfb3d179924f78',
      'Strict-Transport-Security',
      'max-age=7889238',
      'X-Alternate-Cache-Key',
      'cacheable:57d4938b6eec0948258100bed68b0d2d',
      'X-Cache',
      'miss',
      'Set-Cookie',
      'secure_customer_sig=; path=/; expires=Mon, 04 Jun 2040 05:44:00 GMT; secure; HttpOnly',
      'X-Shopify-Stage',
      'production',
      'Content-Security-Policy',
      "block-all-mixed-content; frame-ancestors 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests; report-uri /csp-report?source%5Baction%5D=challenge&source%5Bapp%5D=Shopify&source%5Bcontroller%5D=storefront_section%2Fcaptcha_throttle&source%5Bsection%5D=storefront&source%5Buuid%5D=253b7e9b-919d-49b2-b508-865869943bbe",
      'X-Content-Type-Options',
      'nosniff',
      'X-Download-Options',
      'noopen',
      'X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies',
      'none',
      'X-XSS-Protection',
      '1; mode=block; report=/xss-report?source%5Baction%5D=challenge&source%5Bapp%5D=Shopify&source%5Bcontroller%5D=storefront_section%2Fcaptcha_throttle&source%5Bsection%5D=storefront&source%5Buuid%5D=253b7e9b-919d-49b2-b508-865869943bbe',
      'X-Dc',
      'gcp-us-central1,gcp-us-east1,gcp-us-east1',
      'X-Request-ID',
      '253b7e9b-919d-49b2-b508-865869943bbe',
      'Set-Cookie',
      'cart_currency=JPY; path=/; expires=Thu, 18 Jun 2020 05:44:00 GMT',
      'Set-Cookie',
      '_shopify_country=United+States; path=/',
      'Set-Cookie',
      'cart_sig=; path=/; expires=Thu, 18 Jun 2020 05:44:00 GMT; HttpOnly',
      'CF-Cache-Status',
      'DYNAMIC',
      'cf-request-id',
      '031f74a5e20000bcc658ae1200000001',
      'Expect-CT',
      'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
      'Server',
      'cloudflare',
      'CF-RAY',
      '59df56e96822bcc6-SEA',
      'alt-svc',
      'h3-27=":443"; ma=86400'
    ],
    trailers: {},
    rawTrailers: [],
    aborted: false,
    upgrade: false,
    url: '',
    method: null,
    statusCode: 404,
    statusMessage: 'Not Found',
    client: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 205,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _consuming: true,
    _dumped: false,
    req: [Circular],
    responseUrl: 'https://www.neighborhood.jp/challenge',
    redirects: [],
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  aborted: false,
  timeoutCb: null,
  upgradeOrConnect: false,
  parser: null,
  maxHeadersCount: null,
  reusedSocket: false,
  _redirectable: Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      bufferedRequest: null,
      lastBufferedRequest: null,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: false,
      bufferedRequestCount: 0,
      corkedRequestsFree: [Object]
    },
    writable: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      protocol: 'https:',
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      path: '/challenge',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: null,
      hostname: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
      port: null,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/challenge',
      slashes: true,
      host: 'www.neighborhood.jp',
      hash: null,
      search: null,
      query: null,
      href: 'https://www.neighborhood.jp/challenge'
    },
    _redirectCount: 1,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 167,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function],
    _currentRequest: [Circular],
    _currentUrl: 'https://www.neighborhood.jp/challenge',
    _isRedirect: true,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
  [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
  [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
    accept: [ 'Accept', 'application/json, text/plain, */*' ],
    'user-agent': [
      'User-Agent',
      'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36'
    ],
    host: [ 'Host', 'www.neighborhood.jp' ]
  }
}
```

Could someone try to explain to me what exactly is going on here and possibly a solution?

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: You can't disable or go around the challenge. This is forced requirement from Shopify when you make two request from the same IP on the register/contact form. By challenge I mean the google recaptcha that shows after multiply submit attempts.

Comment: @drip Thanks for your response. Do you know exactly how one would go about bypassing the captcha? Or maksing the IP? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't, this is a forced spam protection form Shopify and it can't be overwritten or bypassed. That if you are able to use a proxy to mask the server you will probably be able to bypass it, but it's a little bit of an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

In your shopify Admin > Online Store > Preferences turn off captcha for creating users